# C# Need to access Microsoft Management Infrastructure namespace

Tags: c#, .net, powershell-cmdlet

All,
I am writing a Powershell cmdlet.  Got everything working for the cmdlet on my local machine.  Looked at what is needed to access remote machines and it seems I need a reference to Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll in my project.  I have search my system to no avail.

So I hit Google.  I verified I am running Windows 7 SP1.  Downloaded and installed the Windows Management Framework (WMF) 4.0.  No luck.  Still no DLL.  I verified I met the minimum requirements.

I then found a Microsoft page that said version 5 required WMF 4.0 as a prerequisite to the install.  So I upgraded my .Net Framework to 4.6.2.  Then installed WMF 5.0.  Still no .DLL anywhere on my system.

Has anyone experienced this before?  Can anyone shed some light as to what I may be doing wrong?  I am using Visual Studio 2010.  Is this the cause of the problem?

I have continued to search the web and found articles that stated the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure dll was part of the Windows 7 SDK.  Tried installing the SDK with no effect.  Still cannot get the dll load on my system.

Continuing to look for a fix.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I found to get this dll - and reference it automatically within my VS 2017 Project was via packet Manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure -Version 4.0.0
```

As stated here on this Microsoft page: [Nuget Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/)

No Need to install any SDK or so only to get this dll.

Answer (score 3):

could you check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WMI\v1.0` to see whether can find it there ?

Comment: I had neglected to say that I found posts pointing to that location for the DLL.  However, the WMI\V1.0 does not exist on my system.  Although, I do see C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft,

Answer (score 0):

The best resolution I was able to find to this issue after repeated attempts with numerous combinations of .Net frameworks, WMF versions, and Windows 7 SDK's was to install the Windows 8 SDK.